# Caching on different record levels

Tags: database, caching

I store key-value pairs in the database which can be accessed via webservice. The request contains country, district, terminal and the webservice returns the values mapped to these values.
The database might contain record which mapped to country, there are records which are mapped to district etc. for example:

```
Id Country District Key Value
1  DE      D1       K1  Dummy1
2  DE               K1  Dummy2
3  DE      D2       K1  Dummy3
```

So if the input is DE,D1,K1, then dummy1 must be returned, if the input is DE,D3, then Dummy2 must be returned as we do not have District specific value.

I created a stored proc which returns the list with the most proper records for the input. The problem with it, that I can not really use cahcing.

The most records are assigned to country only, but there are exceptions for districts, so I would like to cache the lists, but the key is always different, so

DE,D3
DE,D4
etc will return the same list, but cache would contain it two time as for these two input records...

One other option is to read just country specific records and then district specific records and merge the two list...

Do you have any other ideas how to make the cachin possible
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with caching, it's pretty common practice to use the input parameters as the cache key in a key/value caching system.

So even though DE, D3 and DE, D4 might return the same object, that should be ok. With caching systems I wouldn't be afraid to store the same object more than once. Who knows, in the future the inputs might return different values in the future.

I would just use the inputs to make a key and cache the stored procedure outputs. You can get distributed caches like Memcached or Redis that will make storing lots of data fairly easy if you're concerned about space.

Comment: I would like to avoid storing the same object twice or more as they cn be huger